# Получение скрина изображения исключая собственное окно(DIRECTX, c++)

Tags: c++, winapi, directx

Здраствуйте, есть программа с directx оверлеем. Она создает свое окно где и отрисовывает нужные элементы. По ходу выполнения программы, нужно реализовать скриншот экрана, при этом исключив из него само окно этой программы. Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Вы же знаете, когда делаете скриншот? просто вначале скрывайте свое окно, делайте скриншот и снова показывайте.

Comment: @KoVadim Я думал об этом методе, но мне он показался не очень красивым в плане реализации, так же я еще думаю,что при отрисовке будут мерцания окна, ведь создание скриншота отнимает определенный ресурс, который будет заметен

Comment: А Вы попробуйте. Думаю, будет работать чудесно